# Will the retain count increase when added to an array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, retaincount

I just wanted to know: will the retain count of an object be incremented if it is added to an array or dictionary in Objective-C? Can I release a particular object immediately after adding it to an array or dictionary?

Comment: You could easily answer that yourself (and probably quicker) if you actually bothered to read the documentation!

Comment: @Sven:i read the documentation but as i am new to this plat form i would like to know it very clearly i had some doubt before, now it is clear.

Comment: @joe Blow: i completely support you in this regard joe... This kind of behavior would be discouraging for the new users to get into stackoverflow....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hariprasad,

NS[collection name here] retain objects added to them as NSResponder noted. A few other facts:

1. To your comment "can I release it
   after adding", the short answer is
   yes. Often times I do an
   `autorelease` for objects that are
   bound for containment in a
   collection and won't be needed outside the collection.
2. When you remove an
   object from a collection, the
   reference count is decremented. If
   you want to ensure it won't be
   deleted from memory (next pool
   sweep) you need to retain the
   object.

Comment: For your point 2, autorelease pools are not involved when it comes to addition and removal from a collection.  The objects are immediately retained and released, and if nothing else has retained the object at the time it is removed from a collection, it will be deallocated at that moment, not at a later time.

Comment: @Brad... for point 2 I didn't say anything about autorelease pool. The rest of your comment is restating the same thing I said at that point.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will increase the retain count of the object you added, that is why you can release the object immediately after adding it to the array.

```
NSObject obj1;
obj1=[[NSObject alloc] init];
//obj1's retain count is 1 here.

[array1 addobject:obj1];
//obj1's retain count incremented by 1, so the total retain count is 2.

[obj1 release];
//obj1's retain count decremented by 1, so the total retain count is 1.
```

`array1` will keep the object until the array1 itself is not released.

Answer (score 3):

NSArrays retain any object added to them.

Comment: can i release it after adding

Comment: All the standard Cocoa containers retain objects added to them. That means you can release them right away, if you don’t plan to hold another reference to them. You really should read Apple’s memory management guide.